# I need a regular expression for a string but with ignoring the first character of string

Tags: oracle

String = 12345

I want to have a regular expression pattern to find the 2345 it should ignore first character of the string in oracle.

Comment: This question needs a lot more details and a complete example of what you have been trying to do and why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to ignore the first character of the string, you can use `SUBSTR`

```sql
select substr('12345',2) from dual;
```